# Optimizing function in python

Tags: python, function, optimization, constraints

The function take 4 input as x,y,w,z and I want to optimize the function with constraint as x + y + w + z = 1 and all 4 should be less than 1. How should I approach this task?

Comment: Define your contraints and write some code? As stated, your optimisation has an infinite number of solutions anyway. Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *all 4 should be less than 1* - how they can give `1` as the result if they are all less than `1`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `0.25 + 0.25 + 0.25 + 0.25`

Comment: @roganjosh, I suppose to get that from the OP to be sure

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That's how I've interpreted the question. Each argument should be less than 1. But there's an infinite number of answers. If you allow user input for all 4 variables, they either get it to satisfy the constraint or not. If you want a computer to solve it, there's no logical one answer.

Comment: @roganjosh, I've been thinking of integer arguments at that moment(for some reason), but if they could be floats, then it's not so bad question as it was downvoted

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I like your answer, it was "optimize the function" that threw my understanding off, since this is really just validation and not optimisation. I think it's likely your answer addresses the issue, we'll have to see if there is a response from OP.

Comment: @roganjosh, thank you. It's interesting to get the OP's thoughts. We'll see ...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, the following solution should fit your initial requirement:

```
def checkAllForOne(x,y,w,z):
    args = [x,y,w,z]
    return all(i < 1 for i in args) and sum(args) == 1

print(checkAllForOne(0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3))  # True
print(checkAllForOne(0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3))  # False
print(checkAllForOne(0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0))      # True
```

*Used functions:*
[all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) - to check if each of arguments is less than `1`
[sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) - to check the total sum of the arguments